# React Navigation — Accessing Navigation props from a custom header component

Tags: javascript, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-props

I am exploring the possibilities React Navigation gives you when using custom headers. Right now I am stuck trying to access navigation.props from a CustomHeader component. How can I access navigation.props such as  .goBack() using a button inside another component.

Thank you in advance.

CustomHeader

```
class CustomHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: 80,
        paddingTop: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
      }}
    >
      <Button
      onClick={this.props.handleClick}
      title="Back"
      color="black"
      />
      <Text> Custom header </Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
        title="Info"
        color="red"
      />
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Screen with the custom header

```
class StreamScreen extends React.Component {
  // Custom header
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: <CustomHeader handleClick={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} />,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Button
          title="Go back"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a props to CustomHeader.

index.js

```
<CustomHeader navigation={this.props.navigation}>
```

in `customheader.js` you can access like `this.props.navigation`
or

`const CustomHeader = (navigation) =>{
// You can access like navigation.goBack() etc.
}`

Comment: Let me try that. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: No good. Dang, I always get stuck when there is a need to pass information from one component to another.